# Which is the faster method to determine parity?

Tags: c, optimization, cpu

So when I was taught programming I learned that a simple 'x % 2' would be a nice quick way to determine whether a number is even. I have since started to use 'x & 1' as I believe it is quicker in the CPU (though given todays speeds maybe it's pointless).
Can anyone who knows more about CPUs shed some light on whether this is actually quicker, or is there some simple compiler optimisation going on?

Comment: I feel as though you could answer this by simply looking at an instruction timing chart for the architecture in question, though you need to bear in mind that pipelines can make those misleading at times.

Comment: Or you could just profile it yourself.

Comment: With a modern compiler, it's basically equivalent. `if(i % 2 == 0)` compiles down to a bit test instruction (`testb`) with `gcc -O3`.

Comment: @slugonamission: Hmm, I don't see a bittest instruction. Maybe because my arch does not have one?

Comment: This isn't what parity usually means by the way

Comment: @Olaf and in those cases, I'd assume `and rx, rx, 1`. Infact my normal "wonky" compiler decided to use an AND without any optimisation :S.

Comment: For performance, you are worrying about the wrong thing. If you want to lose weight, should you shave or get a haircut?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C is a compiled language.  It is not assembly language.

It's a compiler's job to know at least as much (usually much more) about your machine's instruction set than you do.

If you know that `x % 2` and `x & 1` are equivalent, don't you think that's the sort of thing your compiler should know, as well?

For any decent compiler, if you write `x % 2`, and the compiler knows that a bit test will be faster on your machine, it will emit code to perform the bit test, all by itself.

The bottom line is that you should write code that expresses your intentions clearly, and let the compiler worry about optimizing it.  Only under rare circumstances can you significantly improve the performance of code with "microoptimizations" like this.  It's worth performing them *only* if you've demonstrated that the code you're trying to optimize is a significant bottleneck, *and* you've demonstrated that the proposed improvement is truly significantly faster.  Otherwise, don't bother: you're probably wasting your time.

But in any case, we can't tell you which way is faster in general, because every machine might be different.  To find out for sure, you're going to have to measure it yourself.

Comment: Summary: Preliminary optimisations are evil! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I went and tested a program with both methods and default gcc compile turned both into 'and eax,0x1'. Interesting stuff :)